# Unity: 2D Background crashes and shows last frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, game-engine

ive build my first mobile game with unity and everything worked fine in the engine but after building and installing it on my phone I get a weird bug. Basically the background of the start menu will show the last frame of your last game after you come back to the menu after playing a game. It's hard to describe so I'll link a video where you can see it yourself. Problem is, ive no idea why this happens, why it only happens on my phone and not in the engine itself and how I solve it or even for what I have to search. Maybe anyone else had this before and can help me? Or at least give an idea?

Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/c5uOL05mldg?feature=share